# Mail Enabled Sharepoint 2010 Loop Detected

Tags: exchange-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have setup a small Sharepoint 2010 deployment and it is working fine, for now. I have run through one of the more popular step by step guides to mail enable the install and what I have is internal and external mail going to my mail enabled list hitting my Exchange 2010 server (on another Win2k8R2 box) and sitting in the submissions queue with a Loop Detected error and they progres no further.

Everything appears OK as per the guide. I have setup an SMTP role on the Sharepoint box, as per the guide. I have setup a new Send Conenctor on the Exchange 2010 server, as per the guide.

Any ideas on troubleshooting here?

Comment: As a followup. I have enabled outgoing mail from Sharepoint - for Alerts. And they are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all modifications, rebooting server and starting again from scratch seems to have sorted the issue out. I swear all my settings were the same and I had done this mutliple times but it seems to have 'stuck' now and been working fine for the past two weeks. i can't see anythign that might have been different from previous attmepts otehr than some kind of 'stuff up' in Sharepoint.

Still scratching my head....